# Error finding gem path installing rails on Ubuntu using Ansible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ansible, rubygems

I installed `rvm` via Ansible on Ubuntu 20.04 as `ansible_user`.  When I try to install rails I get the error shown below. However if I login as the `ansible_user` and `run gem install rails:3.2.22` it runs with no problem. It seems as if it isn't running as the user I installed it as because it doesn't seem to be loading the gem path.

I tried manually editing *login.defs* and putting the path in there as well and still nothing.
I don't know why using Ansible to run the same thing as the same user is not working.

Gem location

```
ansible_user@newweb2:~$ whereis gem
gem: /home/ansible_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/gem
```

Ansible Error

```
fatal: [virtualbox]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable gem in paths: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"}
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: testing
      tasks:
        - name: install rails
          gem:
            name: rails
            version: 3.2.22
            user_install: yes
```

Comment: Is the `ansible_user` in your inventory?

Comment: yes, I have the following line in my hosts file

[testing]
virtualbox ansible_host=192.168.1.27 ansible_user=ansible_user ansible_port=8022

Comment: Just out of curiouslity, could you `echo $PATH` with `ansible_user`, but not from Ansible?

Comment: ```/home/ansible_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/bin:/home/ansible_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@global/bin:/home/ansible_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ansible_user/.rvm/bin:/home/ansible_user/.rvm/bin```

Comment: So when you installed it, `rvm` udpated your path, but Ansible is not using the shell to do the gem installation. Two ways to fix it: install gem globally, so it is accessible in `/usr/local/bin` and so Ansible will be able to use it. Or, specify the [`executable` path of this task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gem_module.html#parameter-executable)

Comment: I tried actually specifying the executable path before but then it couldnt find ruby

```executable: '/home/anisble_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/gem'```

Error

```fatal: [virtualbox]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/ansible_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/gem query -n '^rails$'", "msg": "/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory", "rc": 127, "stderr": "/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory\n", "stderr_lines": ["/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []} ```

Comment: Also changing ```user_install: yes``` to no makes no difference in the errors I get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its the most ideal solution but this seem to work over using ansibles native gem options.

```
- hosts: testing
  tasks:
    - name: install rails
      shell: '/home/ansible_user/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.8 do gem install rails:3.2.22'
```